# Vaadin Java with Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I am new to java vaadin framework. I have installed APACHE TOMCAT 6 and vaadin on my Eclipse Indigo and trying to develop my first project in it. But when i choose Debug on server or Run on server, i got 404 resource not found error. Dont understand why this is so. my code is :

```
package com.example.firstap;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.*; 

public class FirstapApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("Firstap Application");
        Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
        mainWindow.addComponent(label);
        setMainWindow(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could get a 404 error if your servlet mapping isn't configured correctly in `web.xml`. Please add the contents of your `web.xml` to the question and we might be able to help you with it.

Comment: What's the URL your browser is trying to connect to? Do you see anything peculiar in Tomcat's logs?

Comment: Servlet-name : Vaadinapp Application

Servlet-class : com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet


init param :

Description : Vaadin application class to start
param-name : application
param-value : com.example.vaadinapp.VaadinappApplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can happen depending on how you click on "Debug on Server" or "Run on Server".

Instead of selecting the main file (FirstapApplication.java) and clicking "Run", click on the project name and select "Run on Server". This will launch the app properly and bring up a web browser in Eclipse displaying the hello world.